# UITextField auto-completion callback

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, uitextfielddelegate, uitextviewdelegate

I am using a library for field validation which relies on `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`. It simply validates fields in a form when this notification gets fired and sets a form state (like `invalid`, `eligible`, `submittable`).

However, when I auto-complete using `tab` in any field, `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:string:` delegate method gets called but `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` or `UIControlEventEditingChanged` does not get fired so the validation library cannot function.

To clarify;

[image]

At this point;

- If I tap on `tab`, `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` does NOT get fired.
- If I tap on `space`, `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` gets fired.

Questions:

1. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?
2. Is there a callback for auto-completion so that I can trigger validation myself for this case?

Comment: Did you have a solution to this?

Comment: Hmmm unfortunately no. Using `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:string:` method for validation right now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I turned to this method too.